# Memory Leaks with sound synthesis

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, xcode, core-audio

So I feel like this is kind of a hard question to ask correctly, but here is my best shot.

I am writing an iPhone app in obj-c, but it involves sound synthesis, and the tutorial in core audio I did used sound synthesis programmed in what I believe is C (or maybe C++, I asked someone I know who uses C++ and he didn't recognize it, but the tutorial told me to change file names to .mm for C++).  The problem that comes up is that I have huge memory leaks, most likely because I don't know how to properly call things.

When ever this portion of the code is used, I get a ton of errors that read like this:
2011-08-23 10:18:08.769 myProgram[451:5e03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x171e90 of class _NSCallStackArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Using instruments, I have found where the leak occurs and have put a comment in to represent that.

Here is the function where all the leaks come up:

```
static OSStatus renderInput(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
// Get a reference to the object that was passed with the callback
// In this case, the AudioController passed itself so
// that you can access its data.
AudioController *THIS = (AudioController*)inRefCon;

// Get a pointer to the dataBuffer of the AudioBufferList
AudioSampleType *outA = (AudioSampleType *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;

// Calculations to produce a 600 Hz sinewave
// A constant frequency value, you can pass in a reference vary this.

float sinSignal;

for (UInt32 i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; ++i) {       
    outA[i] = 0;
}


THIS->theBall = [[THIS->navDelegate ballsG] objectAtIndex:0];


THIS->amtPlaying = [[THIS->theBall playingLines] count];

//NSLog(@"%i", THIS->amtPlaying);


for (int i = 0; i < THIS->amtPlaying; i++) 
{
    // Loop through the callback buffer, generating samples
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; ++i) {       

        // calculate the next sample
        sinSignal = sin(  [[[THIS->theBall playingLines] objectAtIndex:i] theta]  ); //leak here

        sinSignal *= [[[THIS->theBall playingLines] objectAtIndex:i] volume] ;

        sinSignal /= THIS->amtPlaying;

        // Put the sample into the buffer
        // Scale the -1 to 1 values float to
        // -32767 to 32767 and then cast to an integer
        outA[i] += (SInt16)(sinSignal * 32767.0f);
        // calculate the phase for the next sample

        [[[THIS->theBall playingLines] objectAtIndex:i] increaseTheta:  [[[THIS->theBall playingLines] objectAtIndex:i] incrementer]];
    }

}

return noErr;
}
```

If I can provide any more information to help you understand my question, please let me know in a comment.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are attempting to do your processing in the background you need to add an `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` at the beginning of the function and then `[pool drain]` at the end since you are using possible autoreleased objects. (`ballsG`, `objectAtIndex:`, `playingLines`)

Comment: That got rid of the other leaks, now instruments shows that I am leaking NSAutoReleasePool.

Comment: And you added `[pool drain]` right before `return noErr;` ? Also, whichever method is called when you are starting a new thread the `NSAutoreleasePool` should be the first thing created there, then the last thing done should be to `drain` it in that same method.

Comment: Yes, the [pool drain] statement is right before return no Err; and the NSAutoreleasePool is called first thing in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using any objc code in the audio render thread. Objc code can lock and usually requires some memory allocation/deallocation. These should also never occur within the audio thread since it is a high priority thread. There a large discussion resource on the core-audio-api email list. You can try and make objc work but it's a nightmare. Using c/c++ works just as well without these problems.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response, but the project was due the next day, so I pretty much have not touched it since.  I don't know much as far as c/c++ so I don't know how much good it would have done for me anyway.  Thanks for pointing this out to me, I will keep it in mind in the future or when I get back to the project.